# Is there a measurable space on which we can define a certain set function that is always infinite?

Tags: measure-theory

Is there a measurable space $(X, \mathcal F)$, such that we can define a set function $\mu$ on it, for which $\mu(F) = \infty$ for all $F \in \mathcal F$, however:

$$\mu \left( \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(F_n)$$

For any collection $(F_n)$ of disjoint subsets of $\mathcal F$?

If not, then why do we require that a measure satisfies $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An additive set function $\mu$ with $\mu(\emptyset) < \infty$ must automatically satisfy $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$.

Formally, the set function $\mu$ that is identically infinite is still countably additive, but isn't going to be very interesting. You can't compute a single thing with it - it doesn't *measure* anything in a meaningful way!

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question because it didn't make sense in its original form.